# How to call variable inside function while using require or include outside that function in php

Tags: php

So, can we call a variable inside function using require or include without using it in the function?

This is the example code:

1. Include / Require file (let's say the file is "include.php")

```
<?php
    $var1 = "Some Value";
    $var2 = "Another Value";
?>
```

2. Index file

```
<?php
    require 'include.php';
    function test1(){
        echo $var1;
    }

    function test2(){
        echo $var2;
    }

    test1();
    test2();
?>
```

Expected output :

> Some Value
> Another Value

Comment: No, include/require don’t change anything about how variable scope works in PHP. You could require the file _inside_ the function, if you want those variables available in the _local_ scope of it.

Comment: The best way to go would be to make the functions take a parameter. Read about [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks!!, using `global $var1;` and `global $var2;` into the function and it's works!!

Comment: One piece of advice: unless you really need these variables in a ton of functions across your whole application, avoid using global variables. If you need variable values inside a function, pass them as parameters. It's much easier to track and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of include/require is actually not relevant for your question. An include or a require will only "merge" the contents of other files to your code in order to become available.

As others have mentioned you need to use the `global` keyword. In many other programming languages the global variables are visible inside functions by default. But in PHP you need to explicitly define which variables that should be visible in each function.

Example:

```
<?php  
    $a = "first";
    $b = "second";
    $c = "third";

    function test() {
        global $a, $b;
        echo $a . " " . $b . " " . $c;
    }

    test();   // This will output only "first second" since variable $c is not declared as global/visible in the test-function
?>
```

However, if the variables should be treated as static constants I would recommend you to define them as constants. Constants have a "real" global scope and you do not need to use the `global` keyword.

```
<?php  
    define("A", "first"); 
    define("B", "second");
    define("C", "third");

    function test() {
        echo A . " " . B . " " . C;
    }

    test();   // This will output "first second third". You don't need to use the global keyword since you refer to global constants
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use global is bed practice, And yet it will work

```
<?php
  $v1 = "foo";
  $v2 = "bar";
 
 function test(){
    global $v1, $v2;
    echo $v1 . $v2;
 }
 
 test();
```

Another solution would be to use the design pattern registry:

https://github.com/AnthonyWlodarski/Design-Pattern-Examples/blob/master/registry.php